# Unity Spawned Object doesnt rotate forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Game I shoot Projectiles in the direction where I look...
but for example when I shoot to the right the Projectile is straight and dont go forward. This is what i use to make them move:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * projectileSpeed);
```

[image: Projectile Shoot Forward]
[image: Shooting Projectile but not forward]

[image: Dont rotate in the direction where i looked]

Comment: Is your camera a child of any gameObjects?

Comment: yes its a child of  the Capsule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok before you throw, you need to orient it just like the camera:

```
transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * projectileSpeed);
```

If the object is along the Z axis this should work. Otherwise we'll need to add some rotation to it.

Comment: no i want to shoot at the middle of my screen, but the rotation is wrong.

Comment: You should explain this part further "the Projectile is straight and dont go forward". Maybe describe the picture a bit more, or add additional screenshots that will give us an idea about how things are moving.

Comment: So the actual move direction is fine, you just want it to point to the direction that it's moving, like throwing a spear, right?

Comment: Yeah Exactly, like a Spear ! :)